# asp.net mvc dropdownlistfor not show selectedItem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Model:

```
public partial class BookModel : BaseNopEntityModel, 
               ILocalizedModel<BookLocalizedModel>
{
   public int TranslatorId { get; set; }
   public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableTranslators { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

    var bookTranslators = _customerService.GetAllTranslators();
    foreach (var item in bookTranslators)
    {
        model.AvailableTranslators.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = item.Nickname,
            Value = item.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = item.Nickname == model.Translator
         });
    }   
    return View(model);
}
```

Model.AvailableTranslators does have one item with selected = true but failed to show it as a default value in the View. What am I doing wrong ?

How can i display the selectedItem as the default value ?

View:

```
@model BookModel 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TranslatorId, Model.AvailableTranslators)
```

UPDATE: i changed datatype TranslatorId  to string

```
public string TranslatorId { get; set; }
```

now dropdownlist shows the correct default value, just don't know why?

Comment: Just to confirm: is AvailableTranslatators a SelectList?

Comment: public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableTranslatators { get; set; } >> it's that.

Comment: more precisely, i need the selectedItem to show as a default value. Thanks.

Comment: What is `model.TranslatorId` in this case?

Answer (score 2):

you need to wrap your AvailableTranslators collection into a `SelectList`

try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.TranslatorId,
                       new SelectList(ViewBag.AvailableTranslatators,
                                      "Value","Text",@Model.TranslatorId
                                     ), 
                    new {})
```

so basically, a SelectList accepts following:

```
new SelectList(SelectListItemCollection, ValueFieldName, DataFieldName, 
               SelectedValue);
```

and you might want to take a relook at SelectedValue field that I've given. See if that is what it should be, but you got the idea right?

and as for, why it doesn't work when it is bound to simple SelectListItem List, read all the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689505/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-does-not-honour-selectlistitem-selected)

Comment: that would work but then why cannot with selectlistitem. btw, if i change translatorId to datatype string, it works fine !!

Comment: see the answers of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689505/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-does-not-honour-selectlistitem-selected)